# Replacing XML attribute with MSDeploy in archive.xml which contains a dot

Tags: regex, xml, .net-core, msdeploy, azure-resource-manager

**Introduction**

I'm trying to create an MSDeploy package to be deployed to Azure using Azure Resource Manager. The MSDeploy package however should contain a .NET Core project and I can't find any way on the internet on how to create this so I'm currently trying to create this myself using some MSDeploy commands.

What I'm doing is trying to deploy an Azure Functions application. I created a new 'Function Bot' in Azure and found out this is the package they use to deploy the Azure Function: https://connectorprod.blob.core.windows.net/bot-packages/csharp-abs-functions_formbot.zip

Anyway, after some more hacking around I managed to create a command to produce an output from the dotnet core publish folder that looks quite similar to the csharp-abs-functions_formbot.zip file.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" ^
    -verb:sync ^
    -source:iisApp="C:\path\publish" ^
    -dest:package="C:\path\msdeploy.zip" ^
    -declareParamFile="C:\path\parameters.xml"
```

However when I now deploy this using an ARM template I keep running into path issues where IIS seemingly doesn't understand the path I'm trying to deploy to.

What apparently needs to happen is some more modifications to the archive.xml.

*Sample from Microsoft bots package:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MSDeploy.iisApp MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions="H4sIAAAAAAAEAE2QwUrDQBCGk9osFHvpC0geICxt01YRctB6K2oPpR7MZZNMcXGzO+zOVvr0ugtBncM/P8MM388kaZIk36FijzUdBXl/lq01zpyIf0HDO0BlLj1oKvIjWCeNrm75gs/5vMi3XpG3UGnwZIUq8r1vlGx3cDmYT9BVuWhO5d16I7pys4JynUXS8g/wFgBPv4B/dm/NWXZgX5EC0I1jOBxmL6KHMQr6yHRwjp2F8uDSlLEYn11FkdI9ILJ4d7O9r1vTQf1oKMwO0KMSBK5uDAnESRZ2JizILBveMGODuf4B5a6w3iIBAAA=" MSDeploy.ObjectResolver.createApp="Microsoft.Web.Deployment.CreateApplicationObjectResolver" MSDeploy.ObjectResolver.dirPath="Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DirPathObjectResolver" MSDeploy.ObjectResolver.filePath="Microsoft.Web.Deployment.FilePathObjectResolver">
  <iisApp path="C:\code\BotAppTemplates\botapp" MSDeploy.path="2" MSDeploy.MSDeployLinkName="Child1" MSDeploy.MSDeployKeyAttributeName="path" MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions="H4sIAAAAAAAEAE2QwUrDQBCGk9osFHvpC0geICxt01YRctB6K2oPpR7MZZNMcXGzO+zOVvr0ugtBncM/P8MM388kaZIk36FijzUdBXl/lq01zpyIf0HDO0BlLj1oKvIjWCeNrm75gs/5vMi3XpG3UGnwZIUq8r1vlGx3cDmYT9BVuWhO5d16I7pys4JynUXS8g/wFgBPv4B/dm/NWXZgX5EC0I1jOBxmL6KHMQr6yHRwjp2F8uDSlLEYn11FkdI9ILJ4d7O9r1vTQf1oKMwO0KMSBK5uDAnESRZ2JizILBveMGODuf4B5a6w3iIBAAA=">
    <createApp path="C:\code\BotAppTemplates\botapp" MSDeploy.path="2" isDest="AA==" MSDeploy.isDest.Type="Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentObjectBooleanAttributeValue" managedRuntimeVersion="" MSDeploy.managedRuntimeVersion="2" enable32BitAppOnWin64="" MSDeploy.enable32BitAppOnWin64="2" managedPipelineMode=""MSDeploy.managedPipelineMode="2" applicationPool="" MSDeploy.applicationPool="1" appExists="True" MSDeploy.appExists="1" MSDeploy.MSDeployLinkName="createApp" MSDeploy.MSDeployKeyAttributeName="path" />
    <contentPath path="C:\code\BotAppTemplates\botapp" MSDeploy.path="2" MSDeploy.MSDeployLinkName="contentPath" MSDeploy.MSDeployKeyAttributeName="path" MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions="H4sIAAAAAAAEAE2QwU7DMAyGW1gjTeOyF0B9gCraKBsIqQcYNzTYYYIDvaStJyrSOEqcoT09OFIF+PD7l2X7s5ykSZJ8c8Qc4+KM5X3btw49Hkh+QSM7sBpPAxgq8ldwvkdT3cilXMhFkW+CpuCgMhDIKV3ku9Dovn2C0x4/wVTlsjmUt6u16sr1NZSrLJKu/gBvDHj8BfyzO4fHvgP3YomBfhKPs2PtWQ0wsYo+MsPOi6PSAXyaChHPF+cssxYNxTXcJeLw5eaubrGD+gHp3to9DFYrAl83SMraacY9U8Eyz8ZfzMVoZj9zzL4OJwEAAA==">
      <MSDeploy.dirPath path="C:\code\BotAppTemplates\botapp" MSDeploy.MSDeployLinkName="contentPath" />
    </contentPath>
  </iisApp>
</MSDeploy.iisApp>
```

Only changing the path isn't enough as apparently the MSDeployProviderOptions (the long encoded string) also contains data regarding path. What I want to do is do some replacements.

**Problem**

I found out that using msdeploy replace you can replace certain values. E.g.:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" ^
    -verb:sync ^
    -source:iisApp="C:\path\publish" ^
    -dest:package="C:\path\msdeploy.zip" ^
    -declareParamFile="C:\path\parameters.xml" ^
    -replace:objectName=contentPath,targetAttributeName=path,replace="REPLACED!"
```

The command above will replace the path attribute of the contentPath element in archive.xml. However I need to replace the MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions. According to the MSDeploy documentation the targetAttributeName should match a regex expression. I already tried the following but none of them work:

```
-replace:objectName=contentPath.'MSDeploy',targetAttributeName=MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions,replace="5"
-replace:objectName=contentPath.'MSDeploy',targetAttributeName=MSDeploy\.MSDeployProviderOptions,replace="5"
-replace:objectName=contentPath.'MSDeploy',targetAttributeName="MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions",replace="5"
-replace:objectName=contentPath.'MSDeploy',targetAttributeName='MSDeploy.MSDeployProviderOptions',replace="5"
-replace:objectName=contentPath.'MSDeploy',targetAttributeName=.*,replace="5"
```

But none of these seem to work. Anyone has any idea? (Or maybe a better suggestion on how to deploy .net core with ARM)

**Things I ran into when investigating**

Manually rezipping the package also results in failures:
[MSDeploy fails to deploy manually zipped package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626419/msdeploy-fails-to-deploy-manually-zipped-package)