# Create webdeploy package from regular .zip file

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, webdeploy, msdeploy

Currently, as a part of our build-process, we organize the target wwwroot folder structure and build a .zip of it. This is our deployment artifact.

The structure of the .zip file is:

```
/App_Browsers
/App_Config
/App_data
/App_Start
/bin
/data
/dist
/layouts
/views
default.aspx
web.config
```

Is it possible to convert this regular .zip file to a file that can be deployed using webdeploy/msdeploy? Or can webdeploy/msdeploy also deploy regular .zip files?

Comment: We need more information about where this zip is being hosted within the pipeline (System.DefaultWorkingDirectory, Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory etc) and what you have tried. Have you tried using the Azure App Service deploy task, if so what errors are you getting?

Comment: Hi @MattStannett. I have not experienced any specific error. My question is more generic and whether it is possible at all, to use msdeploy to deploy a normal .zip file or whether a normal .zip file can be converted to a msdeploy package. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to convert this regular .zip file to a file that can be deployed using webdeploy/msdeploy? Or can webdeploy/msdeploy also deploy regular .zip files?

The answer is yes.

AFAIK, msdeploy does not support packages, which were zipped using other than built in windows zip archiver.

So, to resolve this issue, you could unzip this regular .zip file, and zipped with built in windows zip archiver, like, the task [Archive Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) task or `7z.exe`.

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626419/msdeploy-fails-to-deploy-manually-zipped-package) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you: msdeploy supports packages build using msbuild OR zip packages build using built-in windows archiver?

Comment: @Hos, AFAIK, the answer is yes.